# Computing $\lim_{x\to0}\frac {4^x-1}{8^x-1}$ algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Q: Solve the following limits using a table of values

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac {4^x-1}{8^x-1}$$

I tried rewriting it as

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2^{2x}-1}{2^{3x}-1}$$

but I do not know where to go from this, I got this question from http://math.bard.edu/~mbelk/math141/LimitsExercises.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

Yes it can be solved algebraically if you write it as

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\cancel{(2^x-1)}(2^x+1)\over \cancel{(2^x-1)}(2^{2x}+2^x+1)}$$

then cancel the factors in common and be left with

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{(2^x+1)\over (2^{2x}+2^x+1)}$$

into which you can just plug $0$ by continuity to get

$$={2^0+1\over 2^{2\cdot 0}+2^0+1}={2\over 3}$$

---

**Note:** If you're doing the problem for credit, then be sure to follow directions and make a table.

Comment: not for credit just for practice

Comment: I thought as much, but wanted to be sure. :-)

Comment: Thanx this really helped never thought of this

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a table of values, as the instructions indicate.

Plug in $x=0.1, x=0.01, x=0.001, x=0.0001$,  calculate the fraction, and see if you can guess where the results are headed.

Comment: I understand that but I was thinking might there be another way using algebra?

Comment: There are many ways, including a very simple solution using L'Hopital's rule.  However following directions is the pathway to good grades.